# Django request.user in model self function

Tags: python, django

I want to get current logged user in my model self function.
I tried this.

```
class My_model(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/',default='uploads/no-img.jpg')
    #other fields
    def show_photo(self,request):
        show_photo = False
        if Photo_request.objects.filter(who=request.user,whose=self.user).exists():
            my_request = Photo_request.objects.get(who=request.user,whose=self.user)
            request_accepted = my_request.accepted            
            if request_accepted:
                show_photo = True                  
        return show_photo
    show_photo = property(show_photo)
```

In my template

```
{% for profile in profiles %}  
    {% if profile.show_photo %}  
        <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{ profile.image }}" alt="image" />
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

but this function not working. I tried without request parameter and custom id, thats working. Is there any problem in my code?

Comment: You cannot pass arguments to functions inside template syntax. You can create a custom template tag to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the custom tag:

*my_app/templatetags/my_app_tags.py*

```
from django.template import Library

register = Library()

@register.assignment_tag(takes_context=True)
def show_photo(context):
    request = context['request']
    profile = context['profile']
    return profile.show_photo(request) # Instead of passing request I suggest to pass request.user here
```

Use it in template by loading the template_tags:

```
{% load my_app_tags %}

{% for profile in profiles %}  
    {% show_photo as show %}
    {% if show %}  
        <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{ profile.image }}" alt="image" />
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tried this, but I got 'bool' object is not callable error.

Comment: This looks good - a bit of explanation:  you have a method on a model that takes an extra arg besides "self" - you cannot pass that arg from the template so you need to find another way to do this.  Aamir is showing you another way.

Comment: @SAFEERN In `show_photo` method of `Profile` model, you are declaring `show_photo = False` which is overriding the method definition rename the `show_photo` variable to something else so that it does not clash. Also remove this line `show_photo = property(show_photo)`

Answer (score 1):

I used `current_thread` function in `threading` package.

1. Add a new middleware in *utils/request_utiles.py* file as following:

   *utils/request_utiles.py*

   ```
   from threading import current_thread
   from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

   _requests = {}

   def get_current_request():
       t = current_thread()
       if t not in _requests:
           return None
       return _requests[t]


   class RequestMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
       def process_request(self, request):
           _requests[current_thread()] = request
   ```
2. Add the middleware in *settings.py* file

   *settings.py*

   ```
   MIDDLEWARE = [
       ...
       'utils.request_utils.RequestMiddleware',
   ]
   ```
3. Use *get_current_request()* function in any models.

   In your code, you can use as following:

   ```
   from utils.request_utils import get_current_request

   class My_model(models.Model):
       user = models.OneToOneField(User)
       image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/',default='uploads/no-img.jpg')
       ...

       def show_photo(self):
           request = get_current_request() # you can get current request in here.

           show_photo = False      
           if Photo_request.objects.filter(who=request.user,whose=self.user).exists():
               my_request = Photo_request.objects.get(who=request.user, whose=self.user)
               request_accepted = my_request.accepted            
               if request_accepted:
                   show_photo = True                  
           return show_photo

       show_photo = property(show_photo)
   ```